# how to know who shared my app and whom get that share

Tags: android, android-intent

i add share button to my app , what i wonder if there is away to know:

who press the share button in my app and whom recieved that share ,

is this possible to do it .

thanks in advance , any help will be appreciated .

My code to add share as follow :

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain"); 
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body"; 
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here"); 
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody); 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add google analytics to your application.
And track shared events like this.

```
  tracker.trackEvent(
      "Share",  // Category
      CategoryName,  // Action
      filename // Label
      ,1);       // Value
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/